# Set initial values for non-editable fields in Django Admin Inlines

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset

My site supports multiple languages. I have an object (Category) that should have 1 or many translation objects (CategoryTranslation) respective to supported languages (they are not so simple, so, please, don't advice to use translation apps). Besides, dependent objects have link to user that creates and last updates them.

I want following in my Category Admin panel:

1. Category fields.
2. Inlined CategoryTranslation object initialized by existing languages. For example, in my site supports Russian and English, 2 (and only 2) inlines should be shown, first should have non-editable field language equals to 'ru', second - 'en'.
3. After Category save, new CategoryTranslation should get created_by field value equals to current user, edited CategoryTranslation should get edited_by field value equals to current user.

Here is what I have done for now:

```
class CategoryTranslationFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def total_form_count(self):
        return len(settings.LANGUAGES)

    def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
        form = super(CategoryTranslationFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
        form.initial['language_code'] = settings.LANGUAGES[i][0]
        return form

    def save(self, commit=True):
        translations = super(CategoryTranslationFormSet, self).save(commit=False)
        for translation in translations:
            if not translation.id:
                translation.created_by = self.user
            translation.edited_by = self.user
            translation.save()

class CategoryTranslationAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CategoryTranslation
    formset = CategoryTranslationFormSet
    max_num = 0

    fields = ('title', 'description', 'language_code', 'created_by', 'created', 'edited_by', 'edited')
    readonly_fields = ('created_by', 'created', 'edited_by', 'edited')


class CategoryAdmin(tree_editor.TreeEditor):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('parent', 'is_list', 'is_active')}),
        (_('Audit'), {'fields': ('created_by', 'created', 'edited_by', 'edited'),
                      'classes': ('collapse',)
        }),
        )
    readonly_fields = ('created_by', 'created', 'edited_by', 'edited')
    list_display = ('is_list', 'is_active')
    inlines = [CategoryTranslationAdmin]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        add_user_for_audit(request, obj, change)
        super(CategoryAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        formset.user = request.user
        super(CategoryAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

As you can see, max_num field of CategoryTranslationAdmin is 0 to prevent adding of additional translations, total_form_count method of form set returns count of supported langauges and forms initialized with available languages on form creation.

**Update**
I also set current user to formset in save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change) method and use him to populate fields of changed objects in save() method of CategoryTranslationFormSet class.

Is it correct?

So now I need:

1. Make language_code field read_only (if I simply add it to readonly_fields tuple, I will not be able to initialize it in form).
2. Understand, is my solution with appending user before save is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
from django.forms.widgets import HiddenInput

def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
    form = super(CategoryTranslationFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
    form.empty_permitted = False # Force the translation

    if 'language_code' not in form.initial.keys():
        form.initial['language_code'] = settings.LANGUAGES[i][0]

    for k in form.fields.keys():
        lang = LANG_CHOICES[zip(*settings.LANGUAGES)[0].index(form.initial['language_code'])][1]
        if k == 'language':
            form.fields[k].widget = HiddenInput()
            form.fields[k].label = u'%s %s' % (form.fields[k].label, lang)
        else:
            form.fields[k].label = u'%s (%s)' % (form.fields[k].label, lang)                

    return form
```